# Replace the occurrences except the last one using Regex

Tags: regex

This is my regex pattern: `[!@#$%^&*().{}/-]`. I want to replace all the occurrences of these characters except the last occurrence. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Look into what a _positive lookahead_ is, you can replace patterns where there may exist a matching pattern infront of it. eg `[!@#$%^&*().{}\/-](?=.*[!@#$%^&*().{}\/-])`

Comment: There is no replacing in pure regex, you need to specify what regex engine you are using.

Comment: I’m using C# framework

Comment: Great, so please share your current code that fails.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that might help:

```
[!@#$%^&*().\{\}\/\-](?=.*[!@#$%^&*().\{\}\/\-])
```

`(?=.*[!@#$%^&*().\{\}\/-])` is a positive lookahead (`(?=` starts the positive lookahead). Meaning the pattern only matches if there is another of these characters somewhere ahead.

`[!@#$%^&*().\{\}\/\-]` your pattern that should be matched (some escapes would be needed)

`(?=` start of psotive lookahead (we need this after)

`.*` any number of arbitrary characters.

`[!@#$%^&*().\{\}\/\-]` again your pattern

`)` end of positive lookahead

The important part is that the lookahead is not part of the matched string as such.

Answer (score 0):

For an “universal” solution I propose you to do this:

`[a-z]*([a-z])`

Replaced by:
`$1`

Adjust this solution for your case and language. You don’t need lookaheads